# Internal extensions show up in the generated interface of a Swift framework

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm creating a Swift framework and have something like

```
// FrameworkClass
internal extension AnotherClass {
    func send()
}
```

When I build the framework, my Framework-Swift.h file looks like

```
@interface AnotherClass (SWIFT_EXTENSION(Framework))
@end
```

And I get the build error `Cannot find interface declaration for AnotherClass`.  I don't want AnotherClass to be used or referenced anywhere outside my framework.  Why is the empty interface being generated when I'm marking it as internal?